# How does this C function count the number of words in a string?

Tags: c, words, counting

I need some help to understand how does the `countWords` function work in the program below.

It is all explained in "Programming in C" written by Stephen Kochan but I didn't get how it works when it comes to "lookingForWord" and "++wordCount" in `countWords` function!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

//function to determine if a character is alphabetic
bool alphabetic (const char c)
{
    if ( (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') || ( c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z'))     
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

// function to count the number of words in a string
int countWords ( const char string[])
{
    int i, wordCount = 0;
    bool lookingForWord = true, alphabetic ( const char c);

    for ( i = 0; string[i] != '\0'; ++i)
        if (alphabetic(string[i]) )
        {
            if ( lookingForWord )
            {
                ++wordCount;
                lookingForWord = false;
            }
        }
        else
            lookingForWord = true;

    return wordCount;
}

int main ( void)
{
    const char text1[] = {"Well, here goes."};
    const char text2[] = { "And here we go... again"};
    int countWords (const char string[]);

    printf( " %s - words = %i\n", text1, countWords (text1));
    printf( " %s - words = %i\n", text2, countWords (text2));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The `alphabetic()` function is a somewhat longwinded way of writing `isalpha(string[i])` (where `isalpha()` is defined with `#include <ctype.h>`), which has the additional merit working better in unusual environments.  The declaration of `countWords()` inside `main()` is unnecessary, too, as is the declaration of `alphabetic()` in `countWords()`.

Comment: Also, the function name is countWords; wordCount is a boolean variable.  ++wordCount is shorthand for wordCount = wordCount + 1.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: if `string[i]` can ever have a negative value the `alphabetic()` function "works" while `isalpha(string[i])` exhibits undefined behaviour. You probably meant `isalpha((unsigned char)string[i])` :)

Comment: @pmg - yes, or you could decide to write `alphabetic()` to use `isalpha()`. Additionally, `isalpha()` might return true for 'ü' and 'Á' which the current incarnation never will.  And if you manage to find an EBCDIC machine, the existing `alphabetic` will return true for non-alphabetic characters.  And so the list goes on.  But you'd probably need to run `setlocale(LC_ALL, "");` to get the benefit of alphabetic accented characters (and you'd definitely have to worry about signed vs unsigned char).

Answer (score 5):

Your function counts the first letter character in a word, then skips over the remaining letters (by setting `lookingForWord` to `false`), and once it hits a non-letter character, it resets `lookingForWord` to true so that it'll count the next letter that it meets as a new word.

Thus, the function will count everything as a separate word that's separated by a character for which `alphabetic()` is false (so it would count "don't" and "o'clock" as two words each).

Answer (score 0):

1. The algorithm starts by initializing `lookingForWord` to true (as we always start looking for a word)
2. Then it loops until it finds the sentinel value '\0'
3. It checks if the `char` at position `i` is alphabetic
4. If yes, we've found a new word, we increase `wordCount` and set `lookingForWord` to false
5. We will keep looping without any increase of `wordCount` because `alphabetic(string[i])` is true but `lookingForWord` is false
6. When we encounter a non-alphabetic character, we set `wordCount` to false so next loop where `alphabetic(string[i])` is true, we will increase `wordCount`

The thing I'm a bit unsure of is why the writer of this code put in the following line:

```
bool lookingForWord = true, alphabetic ( const char c);
```

I compiled the code using:

```
bool lookingForWord = true; //,alphabetic (const char c);
```

but the result stayed the same.